# Map button refresh location

Tags: swift, dictionary, mapkit

I am working on my first swift application for the iPad. Thus far I have a basic mapview with a button in the bottom toolbar, which I would like to refresh and focus onto the users location once clicked.

Currently I have this code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var location: CLLocation!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var refresh: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locationManager.delegate = self

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// location delegate methods

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations.last

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
{
    print("Error code: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

}

How can I get the refresh button to do this? I really need some help as I am new to Swift / xcode :)

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. Why you just don't put the action to the controller and refresh data in your services/managers ?

Comment: How would I go about doing this sorry? I am really new to xcode :( @razor118 I wish for the refresh button to refresh latest location when pressed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Orkhan said you can do it in this way.

If you want to do the action you just simple ctrl-drag to viewController and select "Action".

[image]

After that you can add code to the handler.

```
    var location: CLLocation!
    @IBAction func refreshLocation(sender: AnyObject) {

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    self.location = locations.last as CLLocation
}
```

Comment: Hi, trying this but I get "use of unresolved identified 'locations', in the first line :( Why is this happening? Thank you for your help

Comment: Updated. In locationManager you just save the last location. In button action we set last location to map.

Comment: Where do I put this code? Inside the "func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {" function? Thanks again

Comment: 1. Create variable location

2. Add button action (refresh and put logic

3. Update your locationManager function

Comment: I have updated my question with latest changes, I now get an error when I press the refresh button stating "Thread 1 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION... "

Comment: You should get more information about the exception in output window (console)

Comment: Hmm, I have managed to stop the errors now but I notice nothing change when I click the refresh button, is this normal? I would like the map to refocus to the users location to the centre of the screen once refresh is clicked.. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following 3 line code:

```
@IBAction func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {
    mapView.setCenterCoordinate(mapView.userLocation.coordinate, animated: true)
}
```

**EDIT**

Check the following:

Can you see the dot on the left side of the method?

[image]

I want see your connections inspector. Refresh button and `refresh` method are connected correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can update your location with this function:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    let location = locations.last as CLLocation

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)        
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

If your target is iOS 8, you need to add the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key in your Info.plist.